# PHP Web Application Hosting - Issue with Static IP

Tags: php, web-hosting

All - I have designed a web application on CakePHP and hosting on a personal machine. I bought a static IP and through the static IP, we are able to access the site on the internet. Now, I bought a domain for my web application and forwarding the request from the domain to the static IP. When we type the domain name, it is taking us to the web application, but the problem is, whenever I hover the mouse on any link, I see the static IP in the status bar of the browser, instead of the domain name.

Please help me to get the problem resolved.

Appreciate your response on this.

Comment: What do you mean by "forwarding the request" exactly?

Comment: If the static IP is in your code, why would you think the browser's status bar would show you something else when you hover over the link?

Comment: Either use relative URLs in your application, or use the domain name instead of the IP at the beginning of absolute URLs.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Here is the scenario.
I bought a domain on godaddy - www.abc.com
my static ip is : 72.22.22.226
when I say 72.22.22.226/phpwebapp and hit enter, I can access my application. even, if I say www.abc.com, I can access my application. Because, I am forwarding the www.abc.com request to my static IP.
When I enter www.abc.com and hover the mouse on any link (web page), I see the static ip on the status bar, instead of abc.com/login.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can find the DNS Manager (click launch on the domain manager page), you will see that the first heading is "A - Host", and under the column "Host" you will see an @ . Click the pencil to edit the "Points to" column for the @ and set this value to your ip address.

If you see an a record called www, then make this point to @ .

It should take about an hour to 24 hours to fix itself afterwards. You can use the ping tool as Mark suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your help, user1122069. I went to Go Daddy DNS Manager and tried to create an "A Record". The thing is that, there are many other PHP applications are running on my desktop and if I just enter the static ip and enters the domain name in the browser, it is going to the root on the static ip, instead of the desired application. And I can't enter the "staticip/myapplication" in the A record.Please help me. Thank you

Comment: In order to do this, you will need to setup what are called "virtual hosts" - when your web server sees a certain domain name it will use a certain set of options.

It is not too difficult to do, but it may take you a lot of time to get the configuration just right. You will need to have the ip address pointing or to test with "localhost" vs 127.0.0.1

http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/apache22_vhosts.php

Comment: Thank you so much for your help User1122069. I have followed what you said and it worked like a charm. Thanks for your great help.

Comment: Hello User1122069, I have a quick question. Appreciate if you could help me again.
If I am hosting another application on the same IP, how can we access the other application. If we make another entry in the httpd-vhosts.conf for the Virtual Directory, how could the system knows to which application should the request to be sent. I am bit confused. 

But as of now, I am very good with what you have provided.

Comment: You will see two directives "ServerName" and "ServerAlias" on the link that I sent you. Each virtual host should have a script name that corresponds to the www.domain.com and a ServerAlias of domain.com (alias ie. shortcut). ServerAlias is optional and ServerName could also be another subdomain than www or even the domain. Also the * character works as a wildcard.

If you create a new virtual host, you can reconfigure these directives to serve only those domains by each virtualhost.

Answer (score 1):

icn is correct. Make sure you have an A Record on the domain for the IP address.

Assuming your domain is also with GoDaddy, **[this article](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/7920/adding-or-editing-a-records?locale=en)** clarifies how to add an A Record through their Domain Manager.

I would:
 1. Ping the domain to see where it's pinging to.
 2. Add your A Record
 3. A few hours later (allowing for DNS propagation,) ping it again. It should now be pinging to *your* IP address.

Best wishes

Comment: Thanks for your help, Mark. I went to Go Daddy DNS Manager and tried to create an "A Record". The thing is that, there are many other PHP applications are running on my desktop and if I just enter the static ip and enters the domain name in the browser, it is going to the root on the static ip, instead of the desired application. And I can't enter the "staticip/myapplication" in the A record.Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to change your web server configuration so it runs on the root of the IP for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a "A/AAAA Records"(not forwarding) to your DNS manager. Set domain name as your domain name and ip address as your ip address

Comment: can you please explain bit more about this? My application is on my personal desktop and I have registered the domain on godaddy.com. Once I go to godaddy.com DNS manager, what I would need to do? Please explain

Comment: Hello icn, Thanks for your help. I went to Go Daddy DNS Manager and tried to create an "A Record". The thing is that, there are many other PHP applications are running on my desktop and if I just enter the static ip and enters the domain name in the browser, it is going to the root on the static ip, instead of the desired application. Please help me. Thank you..